# Can i view receipt of live in app purchase receipt by running app in xcode in same device?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Apple in app purchase works in sandbox but in live app even after subscription done by payment, there is no receipt found and app shows no subscription done.

I see subscription done in app store.

Is there anyway we can see in app purchase subscription receipt of live by running app in same device through xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not support attaching the debugger to a production app. You should make sure you're using the Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL helper method to get the file path to the receipt, and capture it after the purchase has returned with a state of 'purchased'. There will always be a receipt. You should also be user server side receipt validation, so send the receipt to your server which will allow you to debug these issues easily.

Comment: Okay so in any case we can not see receipt of live subscription correct?

Comment: There are no official ways to do this. Unless you've built support to export it yourself, as mentioned above. You should look to send and store these on your server.

Comment: Okay, Thank you!